# Creating an order system for customers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having a little trouble with my order system. I believe that the approach that I am taking is all wrong. Basically I am trying to create an order system that allows customers to pick out a pizza with all the ingredients, drinks, coupons etc. Right now my code is not working and I am debugging. I was hoping for a little insight and see if there is another way that I can look at this. I figured that using an array would be the best approach. I also thought that putting that array inside of a function would be best because I could just call the function. I also wanted to be able to list out the certain items out as a menu. I know that in python you can put a list inside of a list and I am not sure if I am able to do that in shell. Please let me know if I am looking at this all wrong. I left all my comments so that you could see what I was thinking as well.

```
#This needs a true/false statement that if the user is interested in the special then the user should get a list of items that
# that the user is able to select from
# the list below are some pf the options that the user can select from

# >>----> Menu Items that the user is able to select from

menuItems()
{

# >>----> Menu option that the customer will be able to to select from
# Menu array should take all the  items that are in the menu
# and add them as a list that the customer can select from

declare -A menu=()
menu=( view_all pizza breads chicken desserts pasta sandwhiches salads drinks extras )
declare -A sizeOfPizza=()
sizeOfPizza=( small medium large extra_large)

# >>----> Crust style of pizza
declare -A crust=()
crust=( brooklyn_style hand_tossed deep_dish thin_crust )

# >>----> Cheese topping on pizza

declare -A cheeseTopping=()
cheeseTopping=( mozzarella )

# >>----> Pizza sauce topping

declare -A sauce=()
sauce=( tomato_sauce honey_bbq_sauce garlic_parmesan_sauce alfredo_sauce ranch

# >>----> Pizza toppings meat/non-meat

declare -A meat=()
meat=( ham beef salami pepperoni italian_sauage sauage chicken bacon philly_stake )

declare -A nonMeat=()
nonMeat=( hot_buffalo_sauce jalapeno_peppers onions banana_peppers diced_tomatoes black_olives mushrooms pineapples cheddar_cheese provolone_cheese green_peppers spinach roasted_red_tomatoes feta_cheese cheese shredded_parmesan )# >>----> Chicken items for the customer to select from wings/boneless

declare -A wings=() 
wings=( hot_buffalo_wings honey_bbq_wings regular_wings habanero_wings garlic_parmesan_wings )
menu=( view_all pizza breads chicken desserts pasta sandwhiches salads drinks 
declare -A bonelessWings=()
bonelessWings=( boneless_chicken )

# >>----> Sandwhich menu items

declare -A sandwhich=()
sandwhich=( buffalo_chicken chicken_habanero mediterranean_veggie philly_cheese_stake chicken_bacon_ranch italian chicken_parm )

# >>----> Salad Menu

declare -A salad=()
salad=( classic_garden chicken_salad )

# >>----> Drink items on the menu

declare -A drinks=()
drinks=( coke sprint fanta crush lemonade tea barq's )

# >>----> Desert items on the menu

declare -A dessert=()
dessert=( brownies chocolate_chip_cookies cinnamon_twist )

# >>----> Speciality Items on the menu 'Menu Specials

declare -A specialityPizza=()
specialityPizza=( chicken_taco cheeseburger pacific_veggie honolulu_hawaiian ultimate_pepperoni memphis_bbq_chicken extravaganzza meatzza philly_cheese_stake deluxe cali_chicken_bacon_ranch buffalo_chic>

# >>----> Extras that the customer can select
}


prompt() 
{




# Prject outline : Creating an order system for customer to order pizza
clear
echo "Welcome to Soprano's Pizzeria."
echo "Please take a look at our menu and let me know what I can get for you."

# Prject outline : Creating an order system for customer to order pizza
# If the user select Yes (Y/y) the user should get the speciality array show up in a list

read -p "Can I interest you in any of our special? [y/n]" selection


#This needs a true/false statement that if the user is interested in the special then the user should get a list of items that
# that the user is able to select from
# the list below are some pf the options that the user can select from

echo "1. "
echo "2. "
echo "3. "
echo "4. "
read -p "Can I interest you in any of our special? [1-4]" specialSelection
if [ "$decision" == "n" ] || [ "$decision" == "N" ]
then
echo "Okay. What can I get for you today? [1-10]" menuSelection
echo "1. View All"
echo "2. Pizza"
echo "3. Breads"
echo "4. Chicken"
echo "5. Desserts"
echo "6. Pasta"
echo "7. Sandwhiches"
echo "8. Salads"
echo "9. Drinks"
echo "10. Extras"
break
fi
# If the user select Yes (Y/y) the user should get the speciality array show up in a list


read -p "Can I interest you in any of our special? [y/n]" selection

#This needs a true/false statement that if the user is interested in the special then the user should get a list of items that
# that the user is able to select from
# the list below are some pf the options that the user can select from

echo "1. "
echo "2. "
echo "3. "read -p "Can I interest you in any of our special? [1-4]" specialSelection

if [ "$decision" == "n" ] || [ "$decision" == "N" ]
then

echo "Okay. What can I get for you today? [1-10]" menuSelection
echo "1. View All"
echo "2. Pizza"
echo "3. Breads"
echo "4. Chicken"
echo "5. Desserts"
echo "6. Pasta"
echo "7. Sandwhiches"
echo "8. Salads"
echo "9. Drinks"
echo "10. Extras"

break
fi

}
```

Comment: "I  know that in python you can put a list inside of a list and I am not sure if I am able to do that in shell." -- you cannot. bash arrays are one-dimensional

Comment: This feels like it is more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). For presenting a menu to the user, use the bash `select` command. There are lots of example here on SO, search for them.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I did a little digging and as you stated arrays are one-dimensional. I am going to post this in a code review.

Comment: You can put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ to fix syntax issues (which you have here).